# Best way to implement a Generic Web Service API

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, json, soap

What is the best way to implement a open/cross platform web service API to an existing .NET App? Not being a strictly .NET friendly API. It already has ASP.NET exposed web services, but need to be built into an generic API allowing inserts, updates and deletes  and returning results based on user criteria in standard SOAP, JSON or other common formats, similar to Google's Data API's.

Are there any frameworks designed for this or is it a build it from scratch project implementing each format/protocol manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Agatha](http://code.google.com/p/agatha-rrsl/) Request Response service layer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Agatha is what you are looking for. Don't get me wrong - it is great at it's intended purpose as a service layer for your app, but I don't think it works as well as a public api.

For any outward facing web api stuff on .NET I would strongly recommend [ServiceStack.net](http://servicestack.net). It meets all your requirements and then some.

The newly released ASP.Net Web API from Microsoft is looking to be a good choice in the future if you are on a project that constrains you from using third party options such as ServiceStack.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RIA services.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices

Answer (score 0):

Leverage [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) (formerly ADO.Net Data services, formerly Astoria). If you need your own data service provider (instead of Linq to Entities for example), see [Alex James' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx)